# Add xml attribute documentname

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm exporting orders to xml
I write in the header of XML

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Document></Document>');
    $xml->addAttribute('documentname','DCustomers');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns','http://www.microarea.it/XTech/1.0.0/XMLSchema');
```

the xml result is

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Document xmlns="http://www.microarea.it/XTech/1.0.0/XMLSchema" documentname="DCustomers">
```

but the tag is reversed i need documentname="DCustomers" tag before in this way

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Document documentname="DCustomers" xmlns="http://www.microarea.it/XTech/1.0.0/XMLSchema">
```

how can i do? thanks a lot!